# Ubuntu 14.04 kvm instance has low resolution

Tags: xorg, 14.04, resolution, kvm-virtualization, gpu-driver

I have a kvm guest instance of Ubuntu 14.04 running with a `vga` type video device. I do not have a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file, I am letting X autoconfigure the video and all devices. When X comes up, the screen resolution is only 800x600. The expected resolution is 1280x768.

I used to get the correct resolution before upgrading to 14.04. The 14.04 guest image was originally cloned from a 13.10 kvm guest instance. When I boot the 13.10 guest now, I still get the correct 1280x768 resolution.

It seems like something has changed for the worse between 13.10 and 14.04, any ideas if this is expected (do I now need `xorg.conf`?) or should be reported as a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new with Ubuntu and I have a similar situation.
I run Ubuntu 14.04 with a SyncMaster 225uw that's not recognized by the system.
However, when running manual commands through the terminal I can reach the max resolution in my monitor.

If you use (I found it in some post with similar issue, but without KVM):

```
xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00" 147.14 1680 1784 1968 2256 1050 1051 1054 1087 -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1680x1050_60.00
```

where VGA1 is my monitor.

You will be able to see the resolution available at displays.
However, as soon as you restart the machine, the resolution also disappears.
I have tried to create a xorg.conf file and so many other alternatives, but it seems as it does not work on Ubuntu 14.04.

Hope that someone can help us!